# Postfix on server bouncing emails sent to same domain emails, external domains working

Tags: postfix, domain, email-bounces

My @example.com email is hosted with Google Apps. I am able to send & receive email to all 4 accounts I have created for @example.com. I also own www.example.com.

The issue is not being able to send emails to ones ending with the same domain, @example.com, persists. I have switched settings in contact forms to point to my personal address, one NOT ending in @example.com, and the form sends.

I go into the terminal and use # echo SERVER MAIL TEST | mail me@personal.com and the email sends. However, when using the same command and sending to webmaster@example.com, the issue occurs.

I have logs and I have a sneaking suspicion I messed up the main.cf, here are pastebins for the log and main.cf

http://pastebin.com/bysqpY4E

http://pastebin.com/x2GK9pPZ

Any ideas? Am I even explaining myself correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You really got configured the MX dns entries of "example.com" domain at google apps, as you can see:

`tampax ~ # dig MX example.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
elemetx.com.        1799    IN  MX  10 alt4.aspmx.l..
elemetx.com.        1799    IN  MX  1 aspmx.l..
elemetx.com.        1799    IN  MX  10 alt3.aspmx.l..
elemetx.com.        1799    IN  MX  5 alt2.aspmx.l...
elemetx.com.        1799    IN  MX  5 alt1.aspmx.l...`

The fact is you got the same domain name configured in the postfix mail server, so when postfix tries to deliver the email to this domain (example.com), it does LOCAL delivery (the e-mail does not go outside your postfix server EVER as it thinks its the owner of the email server of that domain), as you can see:

`Oct  2 10:00:06 elemetx postfix/local[30374]: 48FDB162B19: to=<webmaster@example.com>, HERE ->> **relay=local** <<- HERE, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "webmaster")`

Also, as far as the account "webmaster@example.com" is not configured out in your /etc/aliases, the e-mail is returned to the sender (in this case root@).

(local accounts are defined in this postfix config line:)

`alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases`

Finally, what is causing the problem is:

**mydestination = example.com**

That line makes postfix to 'delivery locally' any e-mail to @elemetx.com, as you can see in the official postfix documentation:

> "The mydestination parameter specifies what domains this machine will
>   deliver locally, instead of forwarding to another machine".

Remove that line or change it for (for example):

`mydestination = localhost`

Restart postfix afterwards:

`/etc/init.d/postfix restart`

Cheers,

Comment: I had to set it specifically as `mydestination = ` thanks.

Comment: You should in fact specify something like "localhost", just because system should have a local MTA.....

Comment: I had tried that already, to the same result.